# Angular app with jquery plugins in ng-view partial

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-plugins

in my angular app there is some partials that i load in ng-view. This partials has some jquery plugins that usually activates by document.ready. But this event not fire when angular load partial in ng-view. How can i call this event to initialize jquery plugins? Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Why do you rely on `ready` event? That's a job for controllers or directives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your partial's controller:

```
 $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () 
 {
   // javascript code here
 });
```